# Парсинг картинок в Android

Tags: java, android

Столкнулся со следующей задачей: мне необходимо сделать парсинг картинок с сайта. При чем по одной. То есть я открываю мое приложение и на главном активити находится рандомная (или нет) картинка с определенного ресурса (типа Яндекс.Картинки)

Помогите, пожалуйста! Вообще не знаю что подключать, какой код куда писать!

Comment: А что уже пробовали сделать?

Answer (score 1):

1. Создаёте разметку с ImageView в ней.
2. Создаёте асинхронную задачу и скачивайте html код страницы.
3. Парсером вытаскиваете URL картинок.
4. Скачиваете их одной из библиотек для этого.
5. Ими же отображаете картинку в ImageView.

Answer (score 1):

http://dajver.blogspot.com/2013/11/android.html
Посмотри вот здесь.
Я использую библиотеку Jsoup. Что бы её подключить, пишешь в гредле 
compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.7.2' 
Код с примерами в инете полно